# Using request.post to send a url

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

On the backend, we have set up a Selenium script to represent our vulnerable client. This script will click any link that you post to the following message board (http://csec380-core.csec.rit.edu:5004/). Your first goal is to demonstrate that this client is functioning. 
Step 1: Setup a server Send our client a message with the link to your page. Use your access logs to verify that the client has connected to your site.

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://csec380-core.csec.rit.edu:5004/', data={'message':'http://52.14.44.145/'})

print r.status_code
print r.text
```

But this is the result I am getting. I have no idea how to send my link to this website.

```
405
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you actually post to this massage board using a get request.
Try this:

```
r = requests.get('http://csec380-core.csec.rit.edu:5004/process_guest?guest_entry=http://52.14.44.145/')
```